# How to compare two pandas dataframe rows and return the value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframe like
 1st Datafarme

```
 index  a   b   c   d
   0    4   5   3   2
   1    1   10  21  34
   2    3   32  1   45
   3    56  42  42  23
```

2nd Dataframe

```
index   a  b  c  d
  LL    2  2  2  1
  UL    42 2  1  8
```

I want excepted output like this.

```
 index  a   b   c   d   result
   0    4   5   3   2    [5,3]
   1    1   10  21  34   [1,10,21,34]
   2    3   32  1   45   [32,1,45]
   3    56  42  42  23   [56,42,42,23]
```

In this I m comparing 2nd dataframe rows with 1st dataframe row. Condition is like if 1st dataframe value is smaller than LL row of 2nd dataframe it will be add in result column likewise if  1st dataframe value is greater than UL row of 2nd dataframe it will be added in result column.

Comment: Your logic is hard to follow and does not make much sense to me right now. How is `5 and 3` smaller than `2`?

Comment: @Erfan He wants them if they are smaller than "LL" value *or* bigger than "UL" value.

Comment: Then can you explain the second row? @Aryerez

Comment: @Erfan 1 is smaller than *LL* 2, 10 is bigger than *UL* 2, 21 is bigger than *UL* 1, 34 is bigger than *UL* 8, so all the items are `True` so they make it into the `result`

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks @Aryerez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do

```py
cond = (first_df<second_df.loc['LL',:]) | (first_df>second_df.loc['UL',:])
first_df['result'] = first_df[cond].apply(lambda x : list(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

this being given that `index` is an index in both your dataframes, if it's not, you could do

```py
first_df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
second_df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

```py
    a   b   c   d   result
index                   
0   4   5   3   2   [5.0, 3.0]
1   1   10  21  34  [1.0, 10.0, 21.0, 34.0]
2   3   32  1   45  [32.0, 1.0, 45.0]
3   56  42  42  23  [56.0, 42.0, 42.0, 23.0]
```

Comment: sorry bro i have done one mistake.. Actual i want to add result column in index and output will be different like this result [1,56] [5,10,32,42][3,21,1,42][34,45,23] in respective columns